# Validate that an end_date is later than a start_date in Rails 4

Tags: forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to determine the best way to validate that an end_date is greater than a start_date in a form.

I don't know how to throw an error if someone were to accidentally select a start_date that was greater than the end_date.

In my form, I have the ability to submit just a single date if the event was only one day (I use javascript to duplicate the start_date select values into the end_date select values), or a start_date and end_date if the event is longer than 24 hours.

The below scenario in the screenshot should trigger a 3rd error with the form.

[image: screenshopt of form]

This is the relevant part of the form:

**event_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@event, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <%= f.check_box :single_day %> Is this a multi-day event?
  </label>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :start_date %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :start_date, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1900  %>
</div>
<div id="end_date_div" class="field">
  <%= f.label :end_date %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :end_date, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1900  %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary", :id=>"event_submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title,   presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  validate  :picture_size

  private

    # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

**events_controller.erb**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Event deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def event_params
        #may need to add the other variables here
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :content, :single_day, :start_date, :end_date, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @event = current_user.events.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @event.nil?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is another *custom validation* on your `end_date` field. You could write something in your model like the following:

```
validate :end_date_after_start_date?

def end_date_after_start_date?
  if end_date < start_date
    errors.add :end_date, "must be after start date"
  end
end
```

This manually adds an error to your model, making sure validation does not succeed.

More information on custom validations: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I also would not have known about custom validations if I didn't read it here. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm wondering where you got your code from then, because it includes one, hence I mentioned _another_ one ;)

Comment: @sevenseacat how can I get the same behavior with time, I have two dropdown `start_time` and `end_time` filled with string values like ['00:00', '00:15','00:30',...,'23:45']. How to validate that?